# Checking if input matches variable with a list of strings

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, variables

I am trying to make a calculator and the user must input which operation they want to use, I have only done addition so far but you get the point.

```
welcome = str(input("Welcome to the calculator, which form of operation do you wish to choose? "))
```

Addition = "Add", "add", "Addition", "addition", "+"

for x in Addition:

```
if welcome == Addition:
    print("Works")
```

I run the code and when I input any of the strings in the "Addition" variable, it does not print "Works"?.

**I have tried without the for loop and it still does not print "Works"**

I am an absolute beginner at python and I just made this stackoverflow account today. I don't know how to write the code in proper code form in this question.

Comment: should addition be a `list`?

Comment: `welcome in set('Add','add', 'ADD','Addition','+')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `in`  we can also use `.lower()` on the input so we have fewer things to match.

```
welcome = str(input("Welcome to the calculator, which form of operation do you wish to choose? ")).lower()
addition = ['add','addition','+']

if welcome in addition:
    print('worked')
```